# Show element if observable value is null

Tags: html, knockout.js

Is it possible to use the Knockout's `visible:` or `if:` data bindings to check to see if an observable's value is (explicitly) null?

I've got two radio buttons, and if either one is checked, it sets an observable's value to either `"True"` or `"False"`.  Otherwise the observable's value is null. I'd like an element to conditionally display if the observable value is null.  The following doesn't seem to work:

```
<div data-bind="visible: specificObservable === null"> Example </div>
<!-- shows the element when null, but not false, nor 'False' -->
```

Comment: How does it "not work" is it always visible? Never visible? What does your view model look like?

Comment: @MattBurland It's not visible; the `visible` expression never evaluates to true despite the fact that the observable's value is null in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guessing that `specificObservable` is an observable, try:

```
<div data-bind="visible: specificObservable() === null"> Example </div>
```

You need to call the observable to get the actual value it contains. `specificObservable` is a function and therefore not `null`, even if the value it contains is `null`.

This is something that can trip you up in knockout because knockout will automatically unwrap observables if they are used by themselves. So if you did:

```
<div data-bind="visible: specificObservable"> Example </div>
```

And it will call `specificObservable` for you and be visible if `specificObservable()` is truthy. But once you start using it in a longer statement you need to explicitly unwrap it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the closing double quote `"` after the call to function `specificObservable()`

Comment: My actual code has closed quotation marks, it's just a typo in my question. I'll edit the question.